# Better yielding tuple-d union case values in list generation

Tags: f#

I have a situation where I'm stitching three different unions into a triplet tuple for building a map/dictionary of strongly typed values keyed on a string.

One of the union cases is very large, the second has three options, and the third has only two. Right now I loop through the large with reflection, and have six yield statements to handle the combinations of the second and third unions.

My code works fine as far as I can tell so far, but I don't quite like having `yield` in my code six times. How can I better represent this situation?

*If needed I can post the code for the unions too.

**Note that `(RawOreName ore).Value` is just a string.

```
let OreDataMap = 
    [
        for oreType in FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<EveOnline.OreDomain.Types.OreType> do
            let ore = FSharpValue.MakeUnion (oreType, [| |]) |> unbox

            yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, Common, IsCompressed)
            yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, Uncommon, IsCompressed)
            yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, Rare, IsCompressed)
            yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, Common, IsNotCompressed)
            yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, Uncommon, IsNotCompressed)
            yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, Rare, IsNotCompressed)
    ]
    |> Map.ofList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use nested loops?

```
let OreDataMap = 
    [
        for common in [ Common; Uncommon; Rare ] do
            for compressed in [ IsCompressed; IsNotCompressed] do
                for oreType in FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<EveOnline.OreDomain.Types.OreType> do
                    let ore = FSharpValue.MakeUnion (oreType, [| |]) |> unbox
                    yield (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, common, compressed)
    ]
    |> Map.ofList
```

That's probably the idiomatic way, but if you don't like excessive indentation you can always align your successive for loops - I think this looks nicer. Also, you can replace the last `do` with `->` to eliminate the need for the `yield` keyword.

```
let OreDataMap = 
    [
        for common in [ Common; Uncommon; Rare ] do
        for compressed in [ IsCompressed; IsNotCompressed] do
        for oreType in FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<EveOnline.OreDomain.Types.OreType> ->
            let ore = FSharpValue.MakeUnion (oreType, [| |]) |> unbox
            (RawOreName ore).Value, (ore, common, compressed)
    ]
    |> Map.ofList
```

Comment: Oh! Actually I meant to explain why I specifically didn't use loops. The second and third unions are not ever going to change, so the extra loops are really superfluous. =)

Comment: I realize they're not going to change, but it avoids writing the yield 6 times, like you said.

Comment: You're totally correct in that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You could use ‘yield!‘ to avoid six yields and duplication of calling RawOreName. More lines though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a couple of nested for .. do expressions and just yield out once?